# Why is theme created returned by a function delayed in its application?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example a function returns a theme, which is altered by some extend (in this minimum example just some extreme ugly modifications...). Adding this function the first time to a ggplot does not do anything, but adding it to any further plot it works as intenden. How can I make sure, that the function works properly alreay in its first application, or where is my error in thinking?

```
require(ggplot2)

# Minimal example: function returning some theme with modifications
mytheme <- function(size = 3) {
  th.my <- theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=size))
  th.my$axis.ticks$size = 1
  return (th.my)
}

# Plot something, applying theme function first time
fig1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
        geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
        mytheme()
print(fig1)

# Now exactly the same, again
fig2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
        geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
        mytheme()
print(fig2)
```

As one can see in the following plots, the first time the theme was not applied, but the second time it worked...

[image: So far, not working!]
[image: Now it works...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `theme_set` changes the default for future calls to `ggplot`, it does not change the "current" theme. If you create your own theme function, it should return a list of changes. Don't bother with `theme_set`. This should work

```
mytheme <- function(size = 3) {
    theme_bw(base_size=size) + theme(axis.ticks= element_line(size = 1))
}

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
    mytheme()
```

Or if you wanted these themes to apply to all future plots, you would just run

```
theme_set(mytheme())
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = hp))
# note we don't need to add it to the plot this time since we've
# set it as the default
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Just to understand the complete workflow: first, `theme_set` does change the default theme, but does not return something useful. Next in my function I defined some modifications, and those where applied correctly. However, the modifcation of the default theme does take place in later calls of `ggplot`, since the current call of `ggplot` already has its default theme. Does this make sense?